# How to display custom error message automatically on Dropzonejs?

Tags: dropzone.js

In php if I can't find a specific key I exit with a message. With the default Dropzone settings, this message is shown when the user hovers over the error X. How can I trigger this error message to display without getting the user to hover over it?

```
// php
$msg = "Sorry!";
exit($msg);

// dropzone JavaScript in html
Dropzone.options.dropPhotosForm = {
   paramName: "file",
   maxFilesize: 20,
   acceptedFiles: 'image/jpg, image/jpeg, .jpg, .png, .jpeg',
   parallelUploads: 1,
   error: function(file, response) {
       console.log(response); // "Sorry"
   }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

you can play with opacity a little bit.
Something like:

```
error: function (file, error) {
                if (file && error) {
                    var msgEl = $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-error-message');
                    msgEl.text(error.message);
                    msgEl.show();
                    msgEl.css("opacity", 1);
                }
            }
```